# How do you pool data cross subjects?

Tags: statistics

I have data from (1) different sessions of (2) different mice of (3) different laboratories. How can I analyze the data of different mice together and pool it while correcting for these three tiers of multiple comparisons?

Answer (score 0):

One approach is [analysis of variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_variance) (ANOVA) which is a framework for analyzing mean differences while controlling for those effects. Typically a mixed-effect model is applied that handles experimental factors of both fixed and random-effects types, with appropriately different interpretations and analysis for the two types.

Comment: Thanks Brian! The mixed-effect model sounds good. ANOVA tests the difference between two or more means, but I want something that does not rely exclusively on the mean but uses the entire signal. I tried Spearman-R correlation but also seems susceptible to noise. I'm thinking to try MMD. Do you know of any good tutorials to get started with the mixed-effect model? Many Thanks!